# strange top padding with Chrome/IE and display:inline on ul list

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have a very plain navigation menu using an unordered list laid out horizontally using `display:inline;`. The previews in my HTML editor show the page coming together just fine. However, when it's viewed in Chrome and IE, there's a strange padding on top of the nav menu and only on the top. Using the process of elimination, I know this is a problem with my CSS for the `<li>` tag but I'm not sure what the problem is.

So far I've tried `display:inline-block`, lowering the font size, setting the `<ul>` tag in the nav menu to `display:inline`, and a myriad other things. None seems to be helping. Any advice for where the CSS went wrong? Here is the HTML in question...

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header"></div>
        <div id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">welcome</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">who we are</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">what we do</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="content">&nbsp;</div>      
    </div>  
</body>
```

And here is the CSS...

```
body {
    background-color: #000000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
    text-align: center;
    }

#header {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    height: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 960px;   
    text-align: left;
}

#navigation {
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #C0C0C0;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    text-align: right;
}

#navigation a {
    color: #00132a;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#navigation a:hover {
    color: #483D8B;
}

#navigation ul {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

#navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0 30px 0 30px;
}

#navigation-symbol {
    font-size: 1em;
}

#content {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

And for interactive fun there's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyaNH/) as well which shows the exact same phenomenon I'm seeing. Thanks ahead for the advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set `margin` to zero

```
#navigation ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
```

Comment: D'oh! I put the margin in the wrong css block when trying that. Works now.